# Changing getter value using state value in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have this getter that get the value of one item in the state:

```
boxdata: state => {
      return state.boxchart.data
    },
```

Now I have another item in state that I use to change the value of getter

Currently I do this when component is mounted but it seems that the data sometimes loads but sometimes does not:

```
computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["boxdata"]),
      ...mapState(['reference_fc'])
    },

mounted() {
 this.boxdata[0].chartOptions.series[0].data[0]=this.reference_fc.NSR.values
}
```

So I wonder how can I ensure that the boxdata getter is already updated on the first time that the component loads?

Comment: You're mutating data in a way that Vue cannot detect. See [Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) in the Vue docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue cannot detect array element assignments. This is explained in [Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

Try this instead:

```
this.$set(this.boxdata[0].chartOptions.series[0].data, 0, this.reference_fc.NSR.values)
```

Comment: Where should I use this? In mounted() in the component?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate data using getters. You should use [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html).

Getters are only to get derived state based on store state. [see here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

In your store :

```js
mutations: {
  setBoxdata(state, value) {
     state.boxchart.data[0].chartOptions.series[0].data[0] = value;
  }
}
```

In your component :

```js
computed: {
  ...mapMutations("setBoxdata")
},
mounted() {
  this.setBoxData(this.reference_fc.NSR.values);
}
```

Comment: While it generally is a good idea to modify Vuex state only within mutations, this answer still has the same problem as in OP. If you directly assign to an array element then Vue cannot detect it and the view will not update. This is explained in [Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).